# Lining numbers in bibitem label

Tags: bibliographies, fontspec

I'm using luatex with `fontspec` and "Minion Pro" font. I want to typeset the labels in `thebibliography` environment in lining numerals instead of text numbers (as it is when you simply invoke Minion Pro), but couldn't achieve this.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: Do you want just the label numbers in the bibliography to use lining figures, or should lining figures be used for all numbers -- including page, volume, and issue numbers -- that may appear throughout the bibliography? It might look a bit odd to have lining figures for the labels and oldstyle figures for everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work (assuming the MinionPro package)

```
\def\@biblabel#1{[{\figureversion{lining}#1}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `newfontfamily` with lining numbers and switch to that family before the bilio:
An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\newfontfamily\LFFam[Renderer=Basic,Numbers=Lining,Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

These are non-lining numbers: 0123456789

{\LFFam
and these are lining numbers: 012345678}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lining numbers should be only in biblabel, not in all bib entry